# How to calculate bitrate with integer only math in C code?

Tags: c, integer, division

I bet what I want to do isn't that hard, but I'm not figuring it out on my own.

I want to calculate bytes per second over a number of milliseconds in C language code without use of float or double.

For instance using only integers, how can I compute bytes per second if 123000 bytes came in the past 1300ms?

Thanks

Comment: bytes * (1000 ms/s) / ms

Comment: `bytes_per_second = (bytes_counted * 1000) / duration_in_milliseconds`; just make sure that the part in parentheses is calculated using an integer type that is large enough to hold the intermediate result. I'd use an `unsigned long`, myself.

Comment: The issue of rounding becomes important, if you are using integers.  With floating-point numbers, the rounding is usually chosen for you (round to even is common).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are using 32 bit system and int is 32 bit data type. Also consider round-off for integer data type

Here is the code for reference.

```
int main()
{
    int bytes_count = 123000; /* total bytes captured */
    int time_in_ms = 1300; /* capture end time - start time */

    int byte_rate_per_second = (bytes_count * 1000)/ time_in_ms; /* It will round-off as it's integer type*/
    int roundoff = ((bytes_count % time_in_ms) * 10)/time_in_ms; /*gives roundoff in one point precision. Use recursion for more precision*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I figured it was something pretty easy, but somehow I wasn't coming up with it.  :)